# SELECT Query Optimisation

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-8.0

I have a simple `SELECT` query, for which me and MySQL disagree as to how to use (or not) the indexes on the table.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  events
    WHERE  `deviceId` = ?
      AND  `type` = ?
    ORDER BY  `start` DESC
    LIMIT  1;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type |               possible_keys                | key  | key_len | ref  |  rows   | filtered |             Extra             |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | ALL  | events_deviceId,events_deviceId_type_start | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1242244 |     1.00 | "Using where; Using filesort" |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

Create:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deviceId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `events_deviceId` (`deviceId`),
  KEY `events_deviceId_type_start` (`deviceId`,`type`,`start` DESC,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1379147 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are 1,400,000 rows in the table, and the query is taking ~1 second to execute.

I was expecting the query to use the `events_deviceId_type_start` index to get the `id` of the relevant record, and then use a `Unique Key Lookup` to get the "extra" (non-indexed) columns requested by the query. e.g. treat the query as something like this;

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM events WHERE `deviceId` = 12 AND `type` = 'target' ORDER BY `start` LIMIT 1)
```

Can anyone shed some light on why MySQL refuses to use the index in this case?

Comment: MySQL seems to "think" that deviceId and type are not selective enough, that it would have to read too many rows via the index and that a full table scan would be more effective.  An earlier execution of a prepared statement with other parameters, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

`DROP INDEX events_deviceId;`

It is in the way of the best index.

"1,400,000 rows", and growing, correct?  Suggest you use something smaller than `VARCHAR(255)` -- such as `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes) or `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte, max of 255).

If `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` conflicts with the charset being used when connecting, that could also cause slow things down.  Considering the application, perhaps `latin1` is valid for all uses.

The `EXPLAIN` usually does not take `LIMIT` into account.  That is, its "1242244" is probably bogus.  Ignore.

Do you really use `updatedAt`?